# Theory: JPEG compression dimension

Tags: image-processing, jpeg

my question is about the theory of jpeg compression. 
Wikipedia and various books are always talking from a **8*8 matrix** to work with.
Do I understand it right, if I got an 16*16 pixel image i got 4 of these 8*8 pixel matrix? 
And not one Matrix from 0-7, 1-8, 2-9, ... 7-15. 
If I am right, what is if (image.width mod 8 != 0) OR (image.height mod 8 != 0) ? 
To i fill the rest of my 8*8 matrix with 0? With the mean value? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the color blocks are subsampled; the blocks in the file are still 8x8, but when expanded again they turn into 16x16 (16x8 and 8x16 are also possibilities).

When the image is decompressed the excess pixels on the right and bottom are cropped off so that the original dimensions are maintained.

Comment: Ok this means if I got an 10*8 image the first matrix is 8*8 and the other pixel matrix would have the matrix 2*8. Then i calculate with the second matrix as a 8*8 instead of a 2*8 matrix and cut the pixel who are too much. But whit with values to i calculate for these pixel? Does it matter?